# Query in WIQL for searching between a date time range

Tags: tfs, wiql

I am trying to define a query in WIQL to search for TFS work items between a date time range but I just couldn't get it working.  It doesn't return any matches.  The following is my WIQL query.

```
SELECT [System.State], [Custom.ExternalID], [System.Title], [System.WorkItemType] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = 'Foo_Project' AND ([System.ChangedDate] >= '04/11/2019 20:20:00Z' and [System.ChangedDate] <= '04/11/2019 20:25:59Z')
```

If I do a search with a single '>=' or '<=" Date/Time in my WIQL query then I would see results.  That led me believe that my query is incorrect.

I am hoping to have a 2nd pair of eyes to take a look at my query and see if there's anything wrong with it.

I am using the Microsoft TFS Java SDK to connect and perform operations on TFS 2015.
https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere